# Access 2010 performance query

Tags: ms-access-2010

Hi I am trying to create a query that can give me the best performing program among several companies.

I have a table that has several companies and the programs there are a couple companies that have a program that others do not so I know those will be the best performing.  I want a query to say for example.

> CompanyTwo,Program One,12.85%
>   CompanyOne,Program Two,12.56% 
>   CompanyTwo,Program Three,1%

..... and so on...

Table looks like this.

> CompanyName, ProgramName,PerformancePercentage,ProgramYear
>   CompanyOne,Program One,10.04%,2015
>   CompanyOne,Program Two,12.56%,2015
>   CompanyTwo,Program One,12.85%,2015
>   CompanyTwo,Program Two,9.5%,2015
>   CompanyTwo,Program Three,1%,2015

Comment: I tried a totals query but I can't get that working correctly.  If I remove the company name and set the percentage field to max it does show me which programs are performing the best however I have no idea which company is responsible for the program that is performing.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a bit complicated and requires either 2 queries or a correlated subquery. Below I provided the latter.

```
SELECT BestPerfByProg.program, Table1.company, BestPerfByProg.BestPerf
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Table1.program, Max(Table1.Performance) AS BestPerf
            FROM Table1
            WHERE table1.period = 2015
            GROUP BY Table1.program
            )  AS BestPerfByProg ON (Table1.program = BestPerfByProg.program) 
                                 AND (Table1.Performance = BestPerfByProg.BestPerf)
ORDER BY BestPerfByProg.program;
```

If you want to make it in 2 pieces, start with the part that is between () and save it as BestPerfByProg

Comment: I need the top performing programs and the companies that are doing the best in those programs.  We have 28 programs and 16 companies we want to know out of those 28 programs which companies are doing the best.  The hope is we can then find out why that company is doing better with that program.  All 16 companies participate in the 28 programs.

Comment: I guess its not top program I need to know which company is doing the best with the 28 programs so I want a list of all 28 programs with the highest percentage and which company is behind the success.  I shouldn't have said top.